# Powershell setting new local users forced password change

Tags: powershell, csv, user-accounts

Afternoon folks,

I've got a quick question. I'm making a script to make local user accounts based off a csv file. I have it all working no problem using the `New-LocalUser` command. What I am curious about is there a parameter string I can add or anything to have it so the user **Has** to change the password upon first login?

I've looked through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1 I just was wondering if there was something I've missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't.  Most of the time, when cmdlets are released, they don't include all functionality for a particular technology (e.g. Get-Service versus Win32_Service).  In this case, New-LocalUser, Get-LocalUser, Set-LocalUser are in this boat.

However, in order to achieve what you're after, the WinNT provider has exposed this functionality for a long time:

```
$u = New-LocalUser -Name test -Password ('123456789' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

$WinNt = [adsi]"WinNT://localhost/$($u.Name)"
$WinNt.PasswordExpired = 1
$WinNt.SetInfo()
```